# customize copyright statement in acm

Tags: acm, copyright

I am using ACM template ,but unable to change this statement how can i edit this statement in footer

The inly thing i found is in .cls file its written

```
\RequirePackage{acmcopyright}
\setcopyright{none}
```

and my tex file

```
\begin{document}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\title{\name: {totle of paper } \\}
```

> Copyright is held by the author(s). This work is based on an earlier
> work: TITLE, in PUBLICATION, {VOL#, ISS#, (DATE)} ©ACM, {YEAR}.
> [http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/{number}](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/%7Bnumber%7D)

[image]